# How we can make ms access db embed in winform application to make it portable

Tags: c, winforms, ms-access

Can any please explain that how we can embed ms access db in our winform application so that it could easily run on other machines with just one file **.EXE** . i have serached a lot but still unable to find an appropriate solution for it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that you want to embed an Access database *application* in your .exe so that forms, reports, etc. created in Access will be seamlessly integrated into your Winforms app?

Comment: Sorry, totally unrelated but I had to laugh at the title of this question when I saw it in the Unanswered list. Seeing MS, Access, and WinForm all in the same line ending with the word "portable" made me shoot soda out my nose. I know it wasn't the intended relational meaning, but at glance, it was too funny.

Comment: Gord, i just want that my application should not require any installation when it runs on other machines...if i have the .exe of application then it should work everywhere...i must not be in need of installation of any dbms(i.e ms access)..

Comment: So you use ms access only as a data storage? Then just put you .mdb or .accdb file along with .exe.

Comment: we can't embed it with project rather than putting it separately in folder.

Comment: It should be possible to do create a blank database with code and then add tables to it.  This is an interesting question.

Comment: But experts are thinking that i have put some vague question here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using an MDB, then the (32 bit) database engine (JET) is part of Windows. As such, there should be no setup requirements for that. If the database is only read and not written to, then you can add it as a resource to the EXE, and when the application starts up, extract the resource into either the TEMP directory, or if it's large and you don't mind leaving caches about, into a subfolder under local application data (CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA). If you do the latter, then the next time the application starts it can check to see whether a valid extracted MDB already exists and use that if it does. You can do a similar thing if the database is to be written to, but only for local storage, in which case the linked-in MDB would serve as a 'template' database.

If you were using Delphi or C++ I'd also suggest investigating SQLite as a possible alternative to JET, though as it's C# I assume (the 'c' tag is a bit confusing) then you won't be able to statically link the SQLite code, which fails the standalone EXE requirement.

Comment: @user2927881 It is a good answer based on what you told us (and, more importantly, what you **didn't** tell us). You could have at least said "Thank you".

Comment: Chris: Congratulations on reaching 1,000 rep. You have been making very good contributions and we appreciate them (well most of us do, anyway...).